# TypeScript union type inference failure

Tags: typescript

It seems that sometimes TypeScript (of recent version) fails to narrow union types even if type guard is present.
Is this behavior a bug or a feature:

Preamble:

```
// some config
interface Config {
    name: string;
    option1?: number;
    option2?: boolean;
}

// arbitrary type
interface Entity {
    a: number;
    b: number;
}

// name aware type guard for entity property-to-config map
// some default config may be replaced with a property name
type TConfigSet<TData> = {
    [P in keyof TData]: (Config & { name: P }) | P;
}

// example of TConfigSet usage
const EntityConfigs: TConfigSet<Entity> = {
    a: {
        name: 'a',
        option2: true
    },
    b: 'b'
}
```

Question:

```
// this function compiles
function TypeLooseFieldToName(name: string | Config): string {
    if (typeof name === 'string') return name;
    else return name.name;
}

// this one doesn't
function TypeStrictFieldToName<TData>(name: keyof TData | { name: keyof TData }): keyof TData {
    if (typeof name === 'string') return name;
    else return name.name; // still keyof TData | { name: keyof TData }, should be shrinked to { name: keyof TData }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in the type checker, because the TypeScript handbook says "a `keyof T` type is considered a subtype of `string`."

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html

As a workaround, the type guard can be inverted to rule out the custom type first:

```
function hasName(obj: string | { name: string }): obj is { name: string } {
    return typeof obj.name === 'string';
}

function getName<TData>(name: keyof TData | { name: keyof TData }): keyof TData {
    if (hasName(name)) return name.name;
    else return name;
}

// compiles with valid keys
getName<Entity>('a');
getName<Entity>({ name: 'a' });

// doesn't compile with invalid keys
getName<Entity>('z');
getName<Entity>({ name: 'z' });
```

You could search the TypeScript Issues in GitHub and file a new issue if this hasn't been addressed previously:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues

Answer (score 0):

`typeof name === 'string'` does not work as type guard for `keyof TData` because apparently `string` and `keyof TData` are assumed to be two different types by the compiler. If you add your own custom type guard for `keyof TData` it works:

```
function TypeStrictFieldToName<TData>(name: keyof TData | { name: keyof TData }): keyof TData {
    if (isKeyofTData<TData>(name)) return name;
    else return name.name; // type of name here is { name: keyof TData }
}

function isKeyofTData<TData>(name: keyof TData | {}): name is keyof TData {
    return typeof name === 'string';
}
```